# Big Omega of $n \log n$

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation, master-theorem

While studying master method at recurrences topic I'm stacked at a point. It is written in the book as:

> $T(n) = 3T(n/4) + n \log n$,
>
> we have $a = 3, b = 4$,
>
> $f(n) = n \log n$, and
>
> $n^{\log_b(a)} = n^{\log_4 3} = O(n^{0.793})$.
>
> Since  $f(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_4( 3)+\varepsilon} )$, where  $\varepsilon \approx0.2$ ....

The authors means that the $n\log n = \Omega(n)$. How will we know this? Is $n \log n = \Omega(n)$ true? Or 
something is wrong?

Comment: See [related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3504/solving-tn-3t-fracn4-n-cdot-lgn-using-master-method/3505#3505)

Comment: It's better to say $n\log n \in \Omega(n)$ instead of $n\log n = \Omega(n)$, I think if you think so, you will have a less problem on understanding this.

Comment: See also [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57/98).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, $ n\log n = \Omega(n) $ is true.

To see why, note that for this to be true, we have to show that $ n\log n \ge cn$ for all $n \gt n_0 $ and $ \exists c \gt 1 $. If we take $ c = 1 $ then, we get $n\log n \ge n$ for all $n \ge 2$. This shows that $ n\log n = \Omega(n) $ is true.